# Excel 2013 VBA to filter multiple pivot tables from single cell not working

Tags: vba, excel

First time posting.

I have an Excel 2013 spreadsheet with three pivot tales on it.  I'm trying to automatically update them by referencing a cell on the same sheet.  The VBA code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only updates when cell B1 is touched
If Intersect(Target, Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Set the Variables to be used and assigns their values

Dim WS1 As Worksheet: Set WS1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PIVOT")
Dim PT1 As PivotTable: Set PT1 = WS1.PivotTables("pgmTable1")
Dim PT2 As PivotTable: Set PT2 = WS1.PivotTables("pgmTable2")
Dim PT3 As PivotTable: Set PT3 = WS1.PivotTables("pgmTable3")

Dim PF1 As PivotField: Set PF1 = PT1.PivotFields("REPORTING_DATE")
Dim PF2 As PivotField: Set PF2 = PT2.PivotFields("REPORTING_DATE")
Dim PF3 As PivotField: Set PF3 = PT3.PivotFields("REPORTING_DATE")

Dim filterCell As Date

'This reassigns the filter to the sheet-defined value
filterCell = WS1.Range("B1").Value

'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT tables
With PT1
PF1.ClearAllFilters
PF1.CurrentPage = filterCell
PT1.RefreshTable
End With

With PT2
PF2.ClearAllFilters
PF2.CurrentPage = filterCell
PT2.RefreshTable
End With

With PT3
PF3.ClearAllFilters
PF3.CurrentPage = filterCell
PT3.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

[Here's the spreadsheet:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcvLf.png)

It's returning

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

[PF1.CurrentPage = filterCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxO8o.png)

This code has worked for worksheets containing single pivot tables in the past.  I'm a relative noob that has kludged this together.  I'm certain that there is a more elegant way to do this update with a for-loop.

Also, I have tried splitting these pivot tables onto their own worksheets without success.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mmm, Why aren't you using "Slicer" in Excel? You can connect multiple pivot tables easily instead of using VBA.

1. Click in any cell in the pivot table.
2. Go to "Analyze"
3. Look for "Insert Slicer"
4. Chose the field that you want use as a filter
5. Right click in the Slicer
6. Look for "Report Connections..." and connect all the pivot tables what you want to filter with that slicer.

Note: All pivot tables need the same source.

[image]

I made this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdBMr0nTlVs&index=3&list=PLu68w-i-LuMn8Yh10OYH2bYHSyUIfa_hX). It is in Spanish but I am using the English Excel version.

Comment: When you have a hammer everything looks like a nail.  Thanks!  That slicer trick worked perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome! Hey research about power query or get & transform. You can download the add-in for free. It will help you a lot in your work.

Comment: I came here with a good reason. My pivot tables come from different sources, so I can't reach all of them with one single slicer.